# jqxgrid multicolumn filter

Tags: filtering, multiple-columns, jqxgrid

I have text input in a page and I would like to use it to filter my jqxgrid. 
It should perform a similar query to the following

```
Select * from users where col1 = 'filterExpression' OR col2 = 'filterExpression' OR col3 = 'filterExpression' ...(for all filterable columns.
```

Where the 'filterExpression' is the text from my textbox.

I found the following code online which half solved the problem for me.

```
function setGlobalFilter() {

    var filtervalue = $('#FilterSubString').val();

    var columns = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('columns');
    var filtergroup, filter;
    // clear filters and exit if filter expression is empty
    $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('clearfilters');
    if (filtervalue == null || filtervalue == '') {
        return;
    }
    // the filtervalue must be aplied to all columns individually,
    // the column filters are combined using "OR" operator
    for (var i = 0; i < columns.records.length; i++) {
        if (!columns.records[i].hidden && columns.records[i].filterable) {
            filtergroup = new $.jqx.filter();
            filtergroup.operator = 'or';
            filter = filtergroup.createfilter('stringfilter', filtervalue, 'contains');
            filtergroup.addfilter(1, filter);

            $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('addfilter', columns.records[i].datafield, filtergroup, true);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am running into is that this applies the filter to all columns but if any of the columns fail the filter expression, then no record is returned. I want records to be return when AT LEAST one column contains the 'filterExpression'.

Hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an "OR" operation between your filters. After looking at the function AddFilter() of the API, you can set an OR operation between two filters on the same column. But look likes AddFilter() doesn't provide a way to do the same between two columns.

You can look at the API here :

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-api.htm

You can also search/ask for this feature here (jQWidgets team usually respond fast):

http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/

But I guess that your best bet is to do it on the server side, and reload your data.